# Incorrect frequency using ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is something I noticed just as I was about to put the histograms in my thesis. I noticed that the frequency did not reflect the correct count as displayed in the graph. To double check I tried this in excel and it was proved that the frequency being displayed in R using the ggplot2 was indeed incorrect. I noticed that in my syntax I had applied the xlim function. I removed that out of curiosity to see the result and then magically ggplot2 produced the correct histogram!

This is the code that I'm using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = variable) )+
       geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
       xlim(0, 40)
```

[image]

The one that is producing the correct histogram graph is this:

```
hist(data$variable, breaks = seq(0, 40, 1), ylim = c(0,700))
```

[image]

Can anybody please help me here? I've spent a lot of time trying to get this to work but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# example data
variable <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 10L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 13L, 15L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
12L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 18L, 16L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 34L, 20L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 
9L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 8L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 14L, 19L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 6L)
data <- data.frame(variable)
```

Comment: can you post information on the variable you are using, e.g. output of `summary(data$variable`?

Comment: Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.00    0.00    1.00    1.69    2.00   34.00

I am still struggling to fix this! Looks like it's got something to do with the 'binwidth'. The histogram plots correctly when the hist() function is used... :(

Comment: sth else, in the first call u use `binwidth=1` in the second u don't... is this so or just a typo?

Comment: also reproducible example would help, e.g. dput(data$variable)

Comment: Not a typo. It works fine without the binwidth being specified. However when I use the hist() function with the binwidth specified it still works. This code works:

my.bin.width<-1

T<-hist(data$variable,breaks=seq(0,40, by=my.bin.width),ylim=c(0,700),
 xlab="XXX",ylab="YYY")

Comment: I'm really confused what results you want to reproduce and what you would expect, I don't think we can help you without a reproducible example. When you use geom_histogram() without specificaiton of binwidth it uses a special algorithm to define breaks. This, of course(!), will give you different results compared to specifying breaks manually.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, should I just paste the 'dput' output with the original question @adibender? Thanks.

Comment: yes please, and the respective codes for "correct" and "wrong" plots

Comment: +1 for putting in effort to make example reproducible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I see, the difference is the specific definition of a bin, i.e. whether you use [0,1) or [0,1] for the first bin. Try

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0,40,by = 1), right = TRUE)
```

or if you don't use explicit breaks, you have to specify origin additionaly, either by `xlim` as you did, or

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, right = TRUE, origin = 0)
```