# GGplot is drawing the wrong y axis for 'counts' in histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
 ggplot(data.frame(dat<-round(rnorm(1000),2)),aes(dat)) +
 geom_freqpoly()+ geom_point(aes(x=-0.78,
 y=sum(dat==-0.78)),colour="red",shape=18,size=6)
```

I drew this plot and when i checked how many times -0.78 occurs by using `sum(dat==-0.78)` , it said it occurs 3 times. But according to the plot -0.78 occurs more than 50 times(the y axis is counts). This seems wrong to me. The following is the plot. If the number occurs 3 times in my data then why does my plot say it occurs more than 50 times?

[image]

Comment: `geom_histogram` and `geom_freqpoly` compute the counts for bins not for each single value, e.g. by default the data is split into 30 bins and the displayed values show the count per bin.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891197/incorrect-frequency-using-ggplot2-histogram (have already voted to close as "caused by a typo", but better to be linked to the other thread)